# Arara crashes in TeX Live 2021

Tags: arara

I found an issue with `arara`in TeX Live 2021.

```
%!TEX TS-program = Arara
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

asdad

\end{document}
```

Arara has been configured in TeXWorks as pointing to `C:/texlive/2021/bin/win32/arara.exe` with `$fullname` as argument.

This is the error I get:

```
_ _ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.CLI.run(CLI.kt:193)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.parsers.Parser.parse(Parser.kt:180)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.parsers.Parser.parse(Parser.kt:17)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.parse(CliktCommand.kt:396)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.parse$default(CliktCommand.kt:393)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.main(CliktCommand.kt:411)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.main(CliktCommand.kt:436)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.CLIKt.main(CLI.kt:271)
C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 1:
java.exe -jar c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\arara.jar aaaaa.tex
```

Java.exe is

```
C:\Users\Uwe>java.exe -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Does the same happen with `java.exe -jar c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\arara.jar aaaaa.tex` from the command-line or is it a TeXworks call problem?

Comment: works ok for me on the command line, but my java is 1.8.0_271

Comment: I guess I found the root cause. My file was simply in R:. not in any subfolder. If I move the file to a subfolder, it runs fine. I'll raise a bug report. @Ulrike Can you confirm?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/issues/69

Comment: I never have or compile files in the root.

Comment: arara 6.1.0 sent to CTAN: https://ctan.org/incoming as soon as CTAN and TL deploy it, I will write a proper answer. `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the report, it is indeed a bug. As detailed [in this issue](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/issues/69), `arara` 6.0 raises a null pointer exception when running from the root directory in the underlying file system hierarchy, e.g,

```
F:\> arara test.tex
```

In series 6.0, `arara` has an experimental project feature ([it is a secret](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41122127#41122127)) and was unable to set a default name for it working with a file in the root directory.
This bug does not affect series 5.0, which is frozen in TeX Live 2020.

We provided a fix, and the new series 6.1 is already available at CTAN. Hopefully it will hit TeX Live 2021 mirrors in a couple days. Soon,

```
$ tlmgr update arara
```

will give us `arara` 6.1.0, which has this issue fixed. Thanks!

Comment: The newest `arara` now has this bug too.

Comment: @Y.zeng Hi, thanks for the feedback! We could not reproduce the issue, could you please expand a bit on that, maybe on a new question? Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes, maybe it it the Windows 11 22H2 not stable. Thanks.